# How to find duplicates in mysql table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with customer info. Normally, the PHP checks for duplicates before they new rows are inserted. However, I had to dump a lot of older rows manually and now that they are all in my table, I need to check for duplicates.

Example rows:

id, name, email, phone, fax

I would like to do a mysql query that will show all ID's with matching emails. I can modify the query later for phone, fax, etc.

I have a feeling I will be using `DISTINCT`, but I am not quite sure how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY email` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to find all duplicate email addresses, then join the resulting duplicate emails with your table to fetch the ids:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT email FROM my_table GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks. However, when I do `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` I get "Resource Id  #2".... How do I set this up correctly?

Comment: Please show the definition of `$result`; also, be aware that the ancient `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ): you should consider using either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you'd like to learn more, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).