# Remove or hide duplicates values in a variable

Tags: php

I have a variable which is calling data from data base:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($consultaReporte); $i++)
            {       
                    $a= $consultaReporte[$i]['FIELD'];                          

            }
```

I am printing this variable in a html table and I am getting:

1. Smith
2. Smith
3. Smith
4. Katy
5. Katy
6. Jonh
7. Michael

How can I hide or remove the duplicates names ?

I want something like:

1. Smith
2. Katy
3. Jonh
4. Michael

[First Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3V98.png) [Second Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s8aw.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated elements of associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857775/remove-duplicated-elements-of-associative-array-in-php)

Comment: Another similar answer: How to find duplicates in mysql table using PHP? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693522/how-to-find-duplicates-in-mysql-table-using-php

Answer (score 0):

you can store them in a map and then get the map keys (map didn't store dublicate keys)

```
$a = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($consultaReporte); $i++)
{        
      $a[$consultaReporte[$i]] = '';                          
}
print_r( array_keys($a) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this by guard filling in temp array

```
 $arrTemp = array();

 foreach ($consultaReporte as $curr) { 
      if (!in_array($curr['FIELD'], $arrTemp)) {
         $arrTemp[] = $curr['FIELD'];
      }
 }

  foreach($arrTemp as $currValue){
    echo $currValue;
 }
```

example :

```
$consultaReporte = array("a", "b", "b");
    $arrTemp = array();
        foreach ($consultaReporte as $curr) { 
             if (!in_array($curr, $arrTemp)) {
                $arrTemp[] = $curr;
             }
        }
     foreach($arrTemp as $currValue){
         echo $currValue . '-';
     }
```

result
[image]

Comment: It is returning a null value

Comment: what is $a ? because I miss understand it, I mean you can instead print from the array itself if you print $a

Comment: I have edited again you can choose, I don't see what exactly  you do by $a

Comment: because to print an array you can use 
 print_r($array) or the foreach I have showed before '

Comment: for some reason I am still getting duplicate values

Comment: With which solution 
Can you explain more what you want to do exactly if you add more of the code you run

Comment: Basically I just want to remove duplicates values in a variable. I just want to have one of each value and remove duplicates. The code I did show is the only one I am using. The other one is just to print the variable in the html table

Comment: The idea you can't have duplicated value in variable, you mean array 
and if so the if guard should make it works

Comment: I understand but for some reason I am still getting duplicate values. I am not using more code but the one I already showed

Comment: can you show me a result from that 

$consultaReporte[$i]['FIELD']

Comment: I added 2 images with the 2 solutions you gave me and its results

Comment: Can you instead print_r($consultaReporte[$i]['FIELD']);

Comment: do you mean just printing $consultaReporte[$i]['FIELD'] ? if it´s so, that way I am still getting duplicate values

Comment: yeah I know , i want just to see how the array looks like, so print it like it is from php

Comment: Printing it that way I am getting the same result than the second solution you gave me. Exactly the same

Comment: Now I edited to the last solution, i think that would work with you

Comment: Now it is replacing my data to letters A and B and it appears only 3 rows from 200 more or less

Comment: You used the example or what 
I meant by example as explanation

Comment: I finally could solve it. Thanks for your help, thanks to your solutions I could think a way by myself to solve it, even if is not the optimal solution. It is working. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way with `foreach()`

```
$temp = [];

foreach ($consultaReporte as $reporte) {
    if (! in_array($field = $reporte['FIELD'], $temp)) {
        $temp[] = $field;
    }
}

// Return the result
return $temp;
```

Comment: I am getting the word 'array' as return

Comment: try to echo $field value:

$temp = [];

foreach ($consultaReporte as $reporte) {
    if (! in_array($field = $reporte['FIELD'], $temp)) {
        echo $field;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my own issue:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($consultaReporte); $i++)
            {                           
                $employeeId = $consultaReporte[$i]['ID_EMPLOYEE'];
                $employeeName = $consultaReporte[$i]['FIELD'];                                      

                if($employeeId == $consultaReporte[$i-1]['ID_EMPLOYEE'])
                {                       
                    $employeeName = '';                                             
                }           

                    $this->cuerpoReporte.= '<tr class="">                           
                                <td width="90" align="left" valign="top" border="0">&nbsp;'.wordwrap(strtoupper(''.$employeeName), 20, "<br />",1).'</td>                                                       
                            </tr>';
            }
```

It is giving me the result expected for me. Nevertheless, I am pretty sure this is not the optimal way of doing this so if someone here knows how to optimize this code or even a new code which give the same result I would appreciate to share it.